# Cordova (Phonegap) https work and debug

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, cordova, google-chrome

There https site with api.

Need work from cordova (angularjs) with it`s https api.

Also I want debug angularjs app in webbrowser (chrome), because its very quick (compared with rebuild and deploy).

Simple code

```js
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: false },
    url: 'https://.../api/Auth',
    data: { email: user, password: password }
    }).
    then(function (response) {
        console.log("0", response);
    }, function (response) {
        console.log("1", response);
    });

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'https://.../api/Auth',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    data: { email: user, password: password },
    success: function (response) { console.log("2", response) },
});
```

1. Result in cordova debug (Visual studio, Windows-x64)

First request

**HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
(XHR): GET - https://.../api/Auth?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1**

*twice, because $http + $.ajax*

Second and next request - **Return correct response (twice too)**

2. Result in chrome

All requests

a) $http use **OPTION** method not POST

b) $http error
**XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://.../api/Auth. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)**

c) $.ajax use correct **POST**

d) $.ajax error 
**XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://.../api/Auth. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://local1.test' is therefore not allowed access.**

**Questions**

1. How work with https in cordova and chrome with the same code?
2. How correct in cordova skip first request and work with as second?

Comment: You are using cordova and angular, why not use ionic? alos the `$http` service in angular is an ajax request so use that and not `$.ajax` since you are using angular. Also its nice to make requests with a factory to keep a separation of concerns

Comment: Thanks about ionic. I have experience with angular. I need simple app. $.ajax is sample of error. Problem in https (CORPS).

Answer (score 0):

As of Cordova 5, you'll need to use the [Cordova Whitelist Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist).

Once that plugin is installed, you need to modify your project's `config.xml` file. For your network requests, you'll need to add `<access>` tags similar to:

`<access origin="http://*.google.com" />`

You'll also need to configure the [Content Security Policy](http://content-security-policy.com/) for your app. I recommend referring to the [Cordova Whitelist Plugin documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) for guidance.